# WatiN clicks the button but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, watin

I have a textfield and a button on the page:

```
<textarea class="txCS" id="text-area"></textarea>
<span id="search-button">Search</span>
```

What I try is simple, write some text in the textfield and click "Search".

```
browser.TextField("text-area").TypeText("Some Text");
browser.Span("search-button").Click();
```

TypeText() works, I see my text gets written on the textfield, Click() also works because I see WatiN highlights it when it clicks the button, but nothing happens when it clicks the button.

When I click the button myself still nothing happens, but when I type something in the textfield manually and click Search then everything works, as if the page knows if a human is interacting with the page and allows searching...

I montiored the events fired when I type someting in the textfield and then tried to fire them using WatiN:

```
searchBox.FireEvent("onmouseover");
searchBox.FireEvent("onmousemove");
searchBox.FireEvent("onmousedown");
searchBox.FireEvent("onfocus");
searchBox.FireEvent("onmouseup");
searchBox.FireEvent("onclick");
searchBox.FireEvent("onkeydown");
searchBox.FireEvent("onkeypress");
searchBox.FireEvent("onkeyup");
searchBox.FireEvent("onchange");
searchBox.FireEvent("onblur");
```

That didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I couldn't solve it, had to switch to Selenium and all is well now.

Comment: You really should be using `<button type="button">Search</button>` in the HTML instead. The `<span>` element was never intended to be something the user could interact with. If a `<button>` element has undesired styles applied to it, then using an `<a>` would work as well.

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript in the browser that affects the text field and the "Search" button? The answer might lie there. You might need to call `textfield.Change()` after typing the text, and before clicking the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reference for others the problem with your code is that you are trying to click a span instead of a button. Unless you 100% sure that the clickable element is a span you should use the following code with Watin:

```
browser.Button("search-button").Click();
```

And that should do the trick